# How to make an arrayformula count values by row?

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I have tried many approaches but I can't seem to figure out a solution to a fairly simple problem with an array formula it seems:

I have a sheet where I get results of individual results of runs of a certain scientific experiment by row.
Next, I'd like to count the occurrence of each output value. Output values can be a number from 1 to 10 so I'd like to individually count how many times the output has been per value.

Also, I'd be then summing up how many individual outputs have been generated in total. So I'd be counting the number of unique outputs within a row.

[image: Screenshot of the test table]

Now my issue is that when using `Arrayformula` the way I normally use it it doesn't work because it would count and sum up everything for the whole Matrix specified. However, I just want the current row to be counted. I tried using `ROW` to get there, but i failed.
I also tried some things like `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(B1:F1),ROW(B2:F5)),ROW(B2:F5),B2:F5))` to understand how to apply the logic, but I fail to get it working as `COUNTIF` version if itself.

[Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wf2lDVXM9FQ1RP7qXOBLU6VpwGQSku6MpxzA04fLMkc/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help and ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Would you be open to using Apps Script [custom formula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)?

Comment: I am not sure if custom formulas would work if the input comes via a google form? I think they process too late and might cause empty cells for other formulas as they try accessing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in H2 use:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(IF(INDIRECT("B2:F"&MAX((ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))=""; 0; 1); 
 FLATTEN(COLUMN(B:F)^0)))
```

in J2 use:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(QUERY({IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN({ROW(A2:A)&"×"&B2:F}); "×")); 
 {SEQUENCE(10)*9^9\SEQUENCE(10)}}; 
 "select count(Col1),Col1 where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); 
 "where Col11 < 100000 offset 1"; 0); 9^9; 10))
```

[image]

---

### update:

H1:

```
={"Total No. of outcomes"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(A2:A); 
 QUERY(SPLIT(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(ROW(B2:F)&"×"&B2:F)); "×"); 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col2 is not null group by Col1"); 2; 0)))}
```

[image]

J1:

```
=INDEX({"Occurence of "&SEQUENCE(1; 10); ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(QUERY({IFERROR(
 SPLIT(FLATTEN({ROW(A2:A)&"×"&B2:F}); "×")); {SEQUENCE(10)*9^9\SEQUENCE(10)}}; 
 "select count(Col1),Col1 where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"); 
 "where Col11 < 999999 offset 1"; 0); 9^9; 10)})
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15ZIV1ZyfhYuL6ex0xzB4BAXxWIQbnPrxcIiI9dwWxrQ/edit#gid=0)

Comment: thank you!
Would you have any idea what to do to get the COUNTIF working? It might be as well via MMULT but I failed finding a good formula for it

Comment: @Henry2004 answer updated

Comment: Wow, great! I have been starring for five minutes at this formula now and I am honest: I still don't get all the magic behind it but I'll be sure to learn about it - seriously thanks a lot!

Comment: I figured out today, when new values arrive at the formula, J2 always ignores the newest row added. So in an array formula, the bottom row is always blank and only calculated upon arrival of a new row. I am not sure why this is, using google forms to submit results

Comment: if this is on the form sheet formula should be placed in row 1. for example the first formula would be: `={"total no of outcomes"; INDEX(MMULT(IF(INDIRECT("B2:F"&MAX((ROW(A2:A)*(A2:A<>""))))=""; 0; 1); 
 FLATTEN(COLUMN(B:F)^0)))}`

Comment: @Henry2004 answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Just an afterthought to this, I think the accepted answer is optimal but I did wonder if you could solve it using only countifs. The answer is yes, but you have to force the array arguments to be the same size and shape otherwise you get the 'array arguments different sizes' error so in J2:

```
=ArrayFormula(countifs(B2:F6,mod(sequence(5,10,0),10)+1,row(B2:F6)+B2:F6-B2:F6,int(sequence(5,10,0)/10)+2))
```

Note the the total number of outcomes column gives the number of *different* outcomes using the formula below in H2:

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(sign(J2:S6),sequence(10,1,1,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your addition! Indeed i realized that the solution for H2 isn't ideal since it counts the total number of outputs, but doesn't count the total number of unique outputs. So the solution above is actually only valid for J2. 
I like your approach for H2 - But I don't get it working, it results in an Error right away :/

Comment: Sorry, the commas should be semicolons in your locale e.g. =ArrayFormula(mmult(sign(J2:S6);sequence(10;1;1;0)))

Answer (score 0):

To answer the subject question "*How to make an arrayformula count values by row?*", rather than the question itself (which has already been answered above), you could use a formula like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(IF(ISBLANK(B2:F),,A2:A),A2:A))
```

This would count the values between columns B and F for each row starting at row 2.

This part of the formula `IF(ISBLANK(B2:F),,A2:A)` replaces each value in the array `B2:F` with the values in Column A. It assumes that the values in Column A are unique, as they are above (Round 1, Round 2, etc).

Then it counts how many times each value in Column A appears and gives you a total for each row.

I realise that I am not answering the question itself, but this page was the top answer when I did a Google search for "*array formula count values in row google sheets*", so I'm answering the subject question in case others land on this page from a similar search.